# Oracle 11g What is recommended charset for international appliaction

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

What NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET and NLS_CHARACTERSET should I use? I use VARCHAR2 to store text. I want to support Chinese and other characters. Application will be writen in Java and Hibernate. Should I use AL32UTF8 for both? Are there any issues using UTF16 instead of UTF8?

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET:AL32UTF8, NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: UTF8 are recommended. UTF16 would cause problems in xml parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UTF-16: Each character is either 2 or 4 bytes long.

UTF-8: Each character takes 1 to 4 bytes to store.
```

usually I use for my foreign languages (russian , turkish, arabic..) utf8 , and I have never had problem with that however in the documentation.

> The benefits of UTF-16 over UTF-8 are as follows:
>
> More compact storage for Asian scripts because most of the commonly used Asian characters are represented in two bytes.
>
> Better compatibility with Java and Microsoft clients
>
> UTF-16 Encoding  is the 16-bit encoding of Unicode. is an extension of UCS-2
>
> UTF-8 is the 8-bit encoding of Unicode. It is a variable-width encoding and a strict superset of ASCII.

Read more in the oracle  [Supporting Multilingual Databases with Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm) and [Choosing a Character Set](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch2charset.htm) maybe contains information might